# How to download and install iXGuard for iOS apps?

Tags: ios, ixguard

There is no any document for working with iXGuard.
How to download?
How to install?
How to working with it?
I have searched in website but not find any guid.
https://www.guardsquare.com/en/blog/ixguard-30-released

Comment: By purchasing it from Guardsquare. I imagine they'll provide details to customers.

Comment: The details aren't that informative !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to request your quotation first before start using iXGuard, after you enroll they will give you access to guardsquare dashboard, And you can download iXGuard package (Documentation include on package)

Comment: How can I whitelist a view controller. I tried whitelist: - name "ControllerA" and -".*ControllerA.*" . Stil app is crash on opening of that view controller

Comment: Name obfuscation only provides blacklists because this technique will try to obfuscate all identifier by default. So instead of register identifier that will be obfuscated, you need to specify what is excluded from being obfuscated.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a small post be me - [Getting Started with iXGuard](https://medium.com/@tejeshwargill/getting-started-with-ixguard-an-obfuscation-app-shrinking-tool-85e1342a5572) — an obfuscation & app shrinking tool.

In this Tutorial, you’ll learn how to implement iXGuard in iOS project and how to strip down your app size by making use of iXGuard — an app shrinking and obfuscation tool. This is a step by step process tutorial for installing iXGuard. Let me know of any issues. I have briefly explained the process below.

It is not possible to write or explain the whole tutorial with images in the stackoveflow answer so a link is provided.

Installing iXGuard

Install iXGuard for your version of Xcode using the standard procedure of installing a package file.
Create an IPA using Xcode

1) Create a file for distribution with Product -> Archive in Xcode

2) Select the archive created in Organizer and select Distribute App.

3) Select iOS App Store then Next

4) Select Export and click Next.

5) Include bitcode for iOS content and Upload your app’s symbols to receive symbolicated reports from Apple After checking the items click Next

6) After setting the certificate related settings, export and save

**Create ixguard.yml**

a. The file may be different for each app. For details, please refer to the Configuration page of iXGuard.

b. From the folder where the exported ipa file is located to the terminal

```
ixguard.yml -o [Obfuscated IPA file name] [Generated IPA file name]
```

When you input the command, ixguard.yml default file is created.

Sample — ixguard.yml (This may vary from Project to Project

Apply iXGuard From the folder where the exported ipa file is located to the terminal ixguard. Please enter the following command in the terminal. config ixguard.yml -o [After obfuscation IPA] [File name] [Generated IPA file name] to apply iXGuard.

If there are no error’s in the operation, an obfuscated ipa file is created.

In the case of [warning] of the log in the terminal, the solution for each case is the same as that of the iXGuard manual

On the Troubleshooting -> Runtime Issues page. — Note: Appearance

Note: Result screen

Test your app

Test the function of the app by using methods such as TestFlight on the actual device.

In particular, tokens, authentication keys, etc. are required for logic-oriented testing.

Obfuscation verification

This part has been verified using the MachOView tool.
1) Perform step 2 to create an ipa file. Include bitcode for iOS content check - Release and create two obsolete ipa and two ipa files that are not obfuscated.

2) Change the extension of the corresponding ipa file to zip and unzip it.

3) There is a Payload folder in the unpacked folder, and check the application file with the app name in it.

4) Right-click on the application and select View Package.

5) Copy the executable file with the name of the app in the package and extract it to an arbitrary directory.

6) Open the executable extracted before obfuscation and executable extracted after obfuscation with MachOView app,

Check the name of the debris and confirm that obfuscation is applied.

Image for reference in tutorial. (Above: prior to obfuscation, below: after obfuscation)

Finally , deploy the app in the App Store –
Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader.

**Application Loader is not available now. You can use Transporter app which is available in Mac app store.**

Comment: What are the steps to install iXGuard ?